# WeChat Your server didn't correctly respond to the Token verification

Tags: php, wechat

If you're a WeChat developer, can you please assist me on the below question?

Firstly, when I need to submit the form I entered my listener URL & a random string token on the form. When I pressed on submit, the message below appeared.

> Your server didn't correctly respond to the Token verification. Please
>   refer to the Message API Guide

What I actually suspected is the data I returned in the function.

I've tried to return 'true' / return 'false' which this is in STRING format
return json_encode( array(true) ) / json_encode( array(true) ) in JSON format

And both also not working, may I know what kind of respond does WeChat accepted at this point? I am truly appreciate if you can assist me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to respond to a request parameter called echostr that is sent by wechat for your server to be properly authenticate. at this point you should not send any other data. In essence this is what happens.

Wechat sends the following params in the request :
   signature (hashed string of a 3 nest params ), token(you provide this), timestamp(a unix timestamp), nonce(random string), echostr

You then do the following :
  -take the timestap, nonce, token and combine them into a an arrray, sort the array alphabetically and convert it into a string and has it using sha1

-compare that string with the signature param.

-If they match, respond to wechat with the echostr param.

ensure that you are not sending out any other messages i.e printing out to the screen etc.

Answer (score -1):

Which programming language you are using for the server?

If PHP, you can refer the sample code on wechat support page.

We used the Django to act as the server and it works.

One lesson learned is some servers may response slowly(more than 5 seconds) that can not pass the wechat Token verification. You can check any other one use the same platform before.

Our server in office is not working but the server hosting on IDC works.